# Rebuild in Features tripping HTTP 500 Error

Tags: drush, features

I am trying to rebuild some features in Drupal 7.37 in preparation for migration and upgrade on a local dev environment using MAMP but I get an HTTP 500 error when attempting to view overrides. Watchdog reports errors with "undefined offset" in schemaorg.features.inc.

Thanks for any help pointing me in the right direction on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Drupal install was on a local environment using MAMP. The problem was solved when I increased the max_execution_time in MAMP's php.ini from 30 to 100.